# finding the minimum value in an array with returned values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d, numpy-ndarray

I have an array for example:

```
[1 2 3 4 
 2 3 4 0
 5 4 0 6]
```

And I want to find the indexes of all the values that are closer to to the value 3.9 (in my example,4)

I tried using :

```
import numpy as np
def find_nearest(array, value):
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
```

and

```
np.where(array== array.min())
```

but none of the options gives me the correct answer.

I do excpect to get:

```
(3,1),(1,2),(2,1)
```

In my original code, I iterate an array with the shape of 3648X5472 so "FOR" loops might be too heavy.

hope to get some help here, thank you

Comment: Ho do you explain `(3,1),(1,2),(2,1)`? This doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], 
              [2, 3, 4, 0],
              [5, 4, 0, 6]])

v = 3.9

b = abs(a-v)

xs, ys = np.where(b == np.min(b))
```

output:

```
>>> xs
array([0, 1, 2])

>>> ys
array([3, 2, 1])
```

Alternative output:

```
>>> np.c_[np.where(b == np.min(b))]
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
# or 
>>> np.argwhere(b==np.min(b))
```

Comment: xs,ys = array([0, 1, 2]),array([3, 2, 1])|
I do except to get (3,1),(1,2),(2,1)

Comment: Can you explain the numbers? First 4 value is row 0, column 3, second is row 1, column 2, third is row 2, column 1. What my output shows

Comment: That's great, the alternative output is exactly what I searched for

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close. When you found the index of the first closest value, you can find indices of the equal values with `np.argwhere:

```
closest = array[np.abs(array - value).argmin()]
np.argwhere(array == closest)
```